# Outlook is adding a right margin I don't want

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm testing a html email is... Outlook, and it's adding a bizarre unwanted margin to the right of my tables.

The two tables should line up side-by-side, 200px each in a 400px parent table (which collapses to 200px on mobile).

The first clue to Outlook's behavior is that the tables are no longer side-by-side. And when the text is selected the added margin is clearly showing:

[image]

Any ideas at all? Here's my code - as you can see I've tried pretty much everything I can think of!!!

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 200px">
  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 400px">
    <td style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 400px">

<table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 200px;">
  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 200px">
    <td style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 200px">Box;</td>
  </tr>
</table><table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 200px;">
  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 200px">
    <td style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-right: none; witdh: 200px">Box;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! I was having the same problem - I was following the tip for responsive layouts from Campaign Monitor and they do recommend tables side-by-side. Also, form my experience, I can not get to have `<td>` behave like rows on iOS Mail (works on Mobile Safari, but no longer works when you send it on an email).

Some more googling and I came to a solution: [it involves setting borders and wrapping the content of the `<td>` on a `<p>`tag](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/removing_unwanted_spacing_or_gaps_between_tables_in_outlook_2007_2010). Check step 3. It works!

Answer (score 2):

That's not how tables work in Outlook, I'm sorry!

You need to include all the data in a single table, or wrap a "super table" around your two tables

```
<table id="supertable">
  <tr>
    <td width="200">
      <!-- Left-hand table goes here -->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Box;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Box;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="200">
      <!-- Right-hand table goes here -->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Unsubscribe here...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Change your details here...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

When it comes to Outlook HTML (i.e. turn-of-the-century table-bases monstrosity) it's best to sketch your design on graph paper to work out your "grid". Then, you can use the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes of `<td>`/`<tr>` elements to lay things out sensibly.

Comment: The margin (or whatever is it) still exists with this code.

What I'm looking for is two, one cell tables to side side-by-side. They need to be tables and not cells so that in the responsive mobile template they can slip down into a single column.

Comment: I hear you, but you have to bear in mind that Outlook's HTML parser is the bastard child of IE 5.5. If you're wanting something slicker for mobile devices you're going to have to do something rather more sophisticated.

Check out http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ for some further info (and a great starting point for any HTML email layout!).